# sending email with gmail smtp

Tags: django, gmail

I have this in my `setting.py` file:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'from@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Pass'
```

I want to send email to destinations posted from a template:

```
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage
destinations = request.POST['destinations'] #this return string with 2 emails ('fst@gmail.com; sd@gmail.com')
EmailMessage(subject, core, to=[destinations]).send()
```

it send email just to the first mail and not for others !
is there any action to make this work for all emails posted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a list to `to`:

```
import re
# or you can use request.getlist('destination')
# I do not know how you generate the two mail addresses
destinations = re.split(r'[;\s]*', request.POST['destinations'])
EmailMessage(subject, content, to=destinations)
```